# The script don't inherit a native class that can manage a script. error

Tags: c#

Im a new Unity user everytime when i try to insert my code this error pops up:The script don't inherit a native class that can manage a script. im a unity user and idk how to fix this
here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
    
    private Sprite [] diceSides;
    private SpriteRenderer rend;
    private int whosTurn = 1;
    private bool coroutineAllowed = true;
    
    //use this for initialization
    private void Start () {
        rend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        diceSides = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("DiceSides/");
        rend.sprite = diceSides [5];
    }
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (!GameControl.gameOver && coroutineAllowed)
            StartCoroutine("RollTheDice");
    }
    
    private IEnumerator RollTheDice()
    {
        coroutineAllowed = false;
        int randomDiceSide = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            randomDiceSide = Random.Rango(0, 6):
            rend.sprite =diceSides[randomDiceSide];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.05f);
        }
        GameControl.diceSideThrown = randomDiceSide + 1;
        if (whosTurn ==1)
            GameControl.MovePlayer(1);
    } else id (whosTurn == -1)
    {
        GameControl.MovePlayer(2);
    }
    whosTurn *= -1;
    coroutineAllowed = true;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please amend your question to provide valid C# code. Please fix typos like `else id (whosTurn == -1)`

Comment: add `unity` tag as it's related to UnityEngine. Appropriate usage of tags can help find answer faster